# Is it possible to render shadows pixel perfect to UV textures without modifying Blender's source code?

Tags: shaders, lighting, pixel-art

To match the style of low poly pixel textured art, I would like to render shadows onto other meshes (at the very least a flat ground plane) with shadow values snapped per pixel of the UV of other textures (for simplicity let's assume all pixels are a uniform size). From my research it doesn't seem possible to perform any task like this in a Shader Node, or even to write a custom GLSL shader to interact with lighting non-trivially in vanilla Blender. Can anyone point me towards a pragmatic solution: I'm not particularly interested in modifying Blender's source code for this and I would prefer not to export to a game engine to render everything.

Update: Here is an example of the per texel lighting I'm talking about

[image: Per texel lighting]

Comment: Kind of like how minecraft looks with smooth lighting turned off?

Comment: Sort of, Minecraft without smooth lighting is just per tile lighting. I'm looking for something more like https://twitter.com/i/status/1372645926569873409

Comment: Does the texture of your existing pixel art _actually_ use one *texture* pixel per pixel-art "pixel" ?  If not and you're rendering your shadows into an existing high-resolution texture then you might be able to render into a lower-resolution target instead...

Comment: Could you screenshot the video from the twitter post you linked and edit your question to include it? Can't view it currently.

Comment: @AC When I say render I mean ideally this would be visible in the 'rendered' mode of the 3D viewport.

Comment: Create a starter file and upload here can encourage more answering. Edit: Baking light onto texture may help.